# cURL and PHP: Stop output to screen

Tags: php, xml, curl, twitter

This PHP script prints all the data minus the XML to the browser (I'm using Chrome).  How can I suppress output to screen?

```
<html>
<head><title>Twitcap</title></head>
<body>
<?php
  function twitcap()
  {
    // Set your username and password
    $user = 'osoleve';
    $pass = '********';

    $ch = curl_init("https://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.xml");

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); // We want to see the header
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); // Set timeout to 30s
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,$user.':'.$pass); // Set uname/pass
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER,1); // Do not send to screen

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement( curl_exec($ch) );
    curl_close($ch);

    return $xml;
  }

  $content = twitcap();
  echo "Hello, world.<br /><br />";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're going to need to switch to OAuth soon. Basic Auth is going away on August 16, 2010.

Comment: Oh man, that sucks. Thanks for the heads up!"

Comment: I love how much traffic this is getting, and the occasional upvote, five years later. I guess it's a pretty common typo.

Comment: had the same issue and this question helped. 9 years later and your question is still getting upvotes. ;)

Comment: The year is 2020. This question still gets upvotes for some reason. Why is this particular issue so common? Is there a bad PHP tutorial out there we're all finding?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You ommitted the `F` in `TRANSFER`, change this:

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER,1);`

To this: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANS **F** ER

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);`

Comment: Yeah, that seemed to do the trick. Thanks a million, that was driving me crazy.

Comment: Strange that you didn't get a "Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSER.." message in your error display or log.

Comment: even with curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0); I'm getting response.
even without "echo". I do not want the response. How to stop it?